# Access to Solr parameters from a ValueSource Parser

Tags: solr, lucene

So I have this class:

```
public class CustomValueSourceParser extends ValueSourceParser {
    @Override
    public ValueSource parse(FunctionQParser fqp) throws ParseException {
        ...
        List<ValueSource> valSources = fqp.parseValueSourceList();
        String iComeFromTheSolrFunctionArguments = 
((LiteralValueSource)valSources.get(0)).getValue();
        String iComeFromTheSolrQuery;
        return new CustomValueSource(iComeFromTheSolrQuery, iComeFromTheSolrFunctionArguments);
    }
}
```

I'd like to take the variable iComeFromTheSolrQuery from the solr query itself--not from the function arguments (because I will be calling the function multiple times and this string is very large).

Is there a way to do this? I tried adding a field to the search criteria, and then calling fqp.getParams(FIELD_NAME), but nothing came through.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.  What I wanted was to add a paramater. Not a field. When Formulating the query, I did this:

```
ModifiableSolrParams params = new ModifiableSolrParams();
params.set(PARAM_NAME_CONSTANT, paramValueString);

solrQuery.add(params);
```

Then in the above code I got the parameter like this:

```
public class CustomValueSourceParser extends ValueSourceParser {
    @Override
    public ValueSource parse(FunctionQParser fqp) throws ParseException {
        ...
        List<ValueSource> valSources = fqp.parseValueSourceList();
        String iComeFromTheSolrFunctionArguments = 
((LiteralValueSource)valSources.get(0)).getValue();
        String iComeFromTheSolrQuery=fqp.getParam(PARAM_NAME_CONSTANT);
        return new CustomValueSource(iComeFromTheSolrQuery, iComeFromTheSolrFunctionArguments);
    }
}
```